# Use nvarchar datatype in SQL Server CE with EF code-first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, nvarchar, ntext

I use SQL Server CE with EF code-first. I have following domain class:

```
public class User:BaseEntity
{
    public User()
    {
        this.UserForms = new List<UserForm>();
        IsAdmin = false;
        IsActive = true;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserForm> UserForms { get; set; }
}
```

and following mapping class:

```
 public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
 {
        public UserMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.FirstName)
                .HasMaxLength(25)
                .IsRequired();

            this.Property(t => t.LastName)
                .HasMaxLength(30)
                .IsRequired();

            this.Property(t => t.UserName)
                .HasMaxLength(10)
                .IsRequired();

            this.Property(t => t.Password)
                .HasMaxLength(30)
                .IsRequired();
        }
    }
```

EF creates the following table for me:

[image]

EF use `ntext` instead of `nvarchar` to make tables and when I run the app I get the following error:

> The ntext and image data types cannot be used in WHERE, HAVING, GROUP
>   BY, ON, or IN clauses, except when these data types are used with the
>   LIKE or IS NULL predicates

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Are you checking the correct database file?

Comment: Yes.I have an empty database file

Comment: What ef version? Have you tried with attributes Ie. MaxLength(30)?

Comment: @ErikEJ Entity Framework 6. No , I am not try MaxLength attribute. I use     this.Property(t => t.FirstName)
                .HasMaxLength(25)
                .IsRequired();

Comment: I've duplicated this problem with `MaxLength` and `StringLength` attributes and as a mapping property. `HasColumnType` does not seem to have any effect. Quite frustrating, I have no workaround yet.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to force the column type?

```
this.Property(t => t.FirstName)
.HasColumnType("nvarchar")
.HasMaxLength(25)
.IsRequired();
```